# What is the problem of giving the right to use sudo vim?

Tags: centos, vim, osx, sudo

I'm using Mac OX 10.10. I would like to know what problems are caused by this:

`user ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/vim /etc/httpd/confs/httpd.conf`

I think this is in /etc/sudoers. I also have Cent OS. Does this commend behave in the same (bad) way?

Comment: I suggest you restate your question.  It's not clear what exactly you're asking, and it would be helpful to know what you think this line should be doing.  Did you write it?  Please provide more context.

Comment: See steve's answer. sudoedit is one solution for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Means folk can leverage this to get a root shell, thereby bypassing your security, eg `:!/bin/sh` from within `vim`.

Or `:r /etc/shadow` and `:w /etc/shadow`.  And so on...

Comment: `:sh` is even easier.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use `rvim` or `vim -Z` to avoid the trivial root shell escape.

Personally I'd write a short script that allowed the user to edit just the necessary files. Then, if any changes were detected it could offer to restart the Apache server, too. The script could even make automatic backups.